# Promise { <Pending> } when attempting to connect to a MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

Following a tutorial I have this:

```
import {MongoClient} from "mongodb";

const user = "user_001";
const password = "imagineTheRealPassHere";
const cluster = "cluster0.unkpm";

const url = `mongodb+srv://${user}:${password}@${cluster}.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

export const connectDatabase = async () => {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

    const db = client.db('main');

    return {
        listings: db.collection('test_listings')
    };
};
```

and this is how it looks in Atlas:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkhBN.png)

notice in the connection string we have *mongodb.net/test*. I am not sure about "test" . It should be

```
<db_name>
```

so I think it should be **"main"** then?  But I did try **"main"** too and still same problem.

Anyway, then on the express side I have this:

```
import express, {Application} from 'express';
import {ApolloServer} from "apollo-server-express";
import {typeDefs, resolvers} from "./graphql/index";
import {connectDatabase} from "./database";

const port = 9000;

const mount = async (app: Application) => {
    const db = await connectDatabase();
    const server = new ApolloServer({typeDefs, resolvers, context: () => db});
    server.applyMiddleware({app, path:"/api"});

    app.listen(port);

    console.log('Fraiser is listening.');

    const listings = db.listings.find({}).toArray();
    console.log(listings);
};

mount(express());
```

But when I run the application, instead of seeing the contents of table_listings table, it just says: Promise {  }

I think something in my connection is wrong but I am new and not sure what else to look at.

Comment: Well, if you have a promise as a result, have you tried `await`-ing for it?

Comment: @raina77ow I have an "await" at the first line of mount function. Are you saying it is needed somewhere else too?

Comment: Have you checked await documentation?

Comment: oh FML! I needed an await for db.listings.find. line too. It kind of returns a promise.